# Odoo/Python how to redirect to a website

Tags: python, redirect, browser, tabs, odoo

In my form view each record should have an icon with a redirection to a specific website. For Example:

Record 1 | www.test.com/a

Record 2 | www.test.com/b

How is it possible to create such a redirection on click?

I tried a button - but I dont know how to redirect in the action:

```
<form string="MyForm">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                          <page string="MyPage">
                                <field name="MyRecords" widget="one2many_list">
                                    <tree string="Records">
                                        <field name="identifier"/>
                                        <field name="recordname"/>
                                        <button type="object" name="open_record_action" icon="fa-external-link" />
                                    </tree>
                                </field>
                            </page>
                            <page>
                            ...
                            </page>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                    ...
                    </group>
                </sheet>
```

In the model:

```
@api.multi
    def open_record_action(self, context):
        ????
```

Also a possible solution would be to store the link in a field in the model and to implement it in the view in this way:

```
<field name="url" widget="url"/>
```

But with this solution the link is displayed. But I want only to see the icon.

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: What are you using? What is `<sheet>`, `<page>`, `<tree>`, etc. ?

Comment: Sheet is the "sheet" of the view. Page is in a way a tab (you can switch between different tabs in the view). Tree is just a summary of the fields.

Aren't this just standard odoo terms?

Comment: Oh cool, sorry for my lack of knowledge there.  I've suggested a retag to use `odoo`/`openerp` instead of `hyperlink`.  People with that specific knowledge will be able to find the question easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "ir.actions.act_url":

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'url': '/forum/%s/question/%s' % (self.forum_id.id, self.id),
    'target': 'self',
    'res_id': self.id,
}
```

Check `website_forum/models/forum.py` for instance.

Comment: Thanks!

I made the following changes:
'url': "http://file:///C:\Users\me\Desktop\picture.jpg", 'target': 'new',
because I want to open a file of the network drive in the browser.

It opens a new tab and uses the file-path as url. But "file:///" is automatically changed to "file///". So it does not open the image and I have to insert the missing ":" manually. Why is the ":" deleted and how to fix?

Comment: Is not supposed to work like that. Upload the file as an attachment and redirect to it.

Comment: Sadly uploading is no solution for me

Comment: put the images inside your package and you can link them. Linking stuff from computer folders is wrong. If you you explain your use case better then someone could help you better.

Comment: There are 10000 images some of them > 200 MB. Putting them into odoo or in the folder would not be a good idea.

Use Case: Opening files from a NAS via Odoo on your Computer

Comment: the serve them via apache or any other webserver or create a controller that exposes them

Comment: How to redirect from other web-site to Odoo pages ?